# Problems with digital signature

Tags: c#, pdf, certificate, digital-signature, smartcard

my name is Mateo and I'm developing a software that signs files using digital signature, with the uruguayan identification card.

I made a program in C# whose objetive is to import signature to PDF documents, using that Identification Card with chip inserted into a Smartcard device. That proyect uses iText 7.2.5.0 library for the signature system, and BouncyCastle 1.8.9.0 for the certificate generation. The program opens a Windows Form with a button; when you clic on it, reads the file in the indicated directory and apply the corresponding mechanism. (see code below).

The problem lies when I go to perform the verification; I know a website with options to do this procediment, and to and verify previous PDF files with one signature applied. When I do the process using a PDF modified with this website, the result is fine. But when I put the file generated from my program, it says “The document has been modified since the last sign”.

The following code represents the functions used in the program. The signature process consists on three steps:

```
using iText.Forms;
using iText.Kernel.Geom;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;
using iText.Signatures;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Ocsp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using Aplicacion_CI.Models;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Cms;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Nist;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using SysX509 = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.X509;
using static iText.Signatures.PdfSigner;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
using System.Security.Policy;

namespace Aplicacion_CI.Controllers
{

    public class PreSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
    {
        private PdfDictionary sigDic;
        private byte[] hash;

        public PreSignatureContainer(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter)
        {
            sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
            sigDic.Put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
            sigDic.Put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
        }

        public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
        {
            using (SHA256Managed sha256 = new SHA256Managed())
            {
                hash = sha256.ComputeHash(data);
            }

            return new byte[0];
        }

        public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic)
        {
            signDic.PutAll(sigDic);
        }

        public byte[] GetHash()
        {
            return hash;
        }
    }
    public class Sign
    {
        public static string NOMBRES = "";
        private string PATH = "C:\\Aplicacion_CI\\PDF\\";

        /* 1 - Generate hash
           Hash will represent the certificate sended by the ID card server when the authentification is succesful
Objetive PDF is located at the PATH string variable.
         */
        public byte[] signProcess(string signedHASH, string certificate)
        {
            byte[] signatureBytes = Utils.hexStringToByteArray(signedHASH);
            byte[] certificateBytes = Utils.hexStringToByteArray(certificate);

            X509Certificate x509Certificate = new X509CertificateParser().ReadCertificate(certificateBytes);

            SignerIdentifier sid = new SignerIdentifier(new IssuerAndSerialNumber(x509Certificate.IssuerDN, x509Certificate.SerialNumber));
            AlgorithmIdentifier digAlgorithm = new AlgorithmIdentifier(NistObjectIdentifiers.IdSha256);
            Attributes authenticatedAttributes = null;
            AlgorithmIdentifier digEncryptionAlgorithm = new AlgorithmIdentifier(Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs.PkcsObjectIdentifiers.Sha256WithRsaEncryption);
            Asn1OctetString encryptedDigest = new DerOctetString(signatureBytes);
            Attributes unauthenticatedAttributes = null;
            SignerInfo signerInfo = new SignerInfo(sid, digAlgorithm, authenticatedAttributes, digEncryptionAlgorithm, encryptedDigest, unauthenticatedAttributes);

            Asn1EncodableVector digestAlgs = new Asn1EncodableVector(signerInfo.DigestAlgorithm);
            Asn1Set digestAlgorithms = new DerSet(digestAlgs);
            ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(CmsObjectIdentifiers.Data, null);
            Asn1EncodableVector certs = new Asn1EncodableVector(x509Certificate.CertificateStructure.ToAsn1Object());
            Asn1Set certificates = new DerSet(certs);
            Asn1EncodableVector signerInfs = new Asn1EncodableVector(signerInfo);
            Asn1Set signerInfos = new DerSet(signerInfs);
            SignedData signedData = new SignedData(digestAlgorithms, contentInfo, certificates, null, signerInfos);

            contentInfo = new ContentInfo(CmsObjectIdentifiers.SignedData, signedData);

            return contentInfo.GetDerEncoded();
        }


        /* 2 - Make signless document and prepare for copy.
When the hash is done, the file is prepared with the sign field.
        */
        public byte[] generateHash()
        {
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PATH + "original.pdf"))
            using (FileStream fout = new FileStream(PATH + "prepared.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            {
                StampingProperties sp = new StampingProperties();
                sp.UseAppendMode();

                PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(reader, fout, sp);
                pdfSigner.SetFieldName("Signature1");

                PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = pdfSigner.GetSignatureAppearance();
                appearance.SetPageNumber(1);

                // Create a pre-signature container for calculating the hash
                PreSignatureContainer preSignatureContainer = new PreSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
                pdfSigner.SignExternalContainer(preSignatureContainer, 32000);

                // Get the document hash calculated by the pre-signature container
                byte[] documentHash = preSignatureContainer.GetHash();

                return documentHash;    
            }
        }

        //3 - Sign the file
        /* Import the signature to the new field made in the previous step.
         * Next, save it into a new file.
         */
        public void signPDF(byte[] Signature)
        {
            //using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PATH + "prepared.pdf"))
            //using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader))
            //using (FileStream fout = new FileStream(PATH + "signed.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            //{
            //    PdfSigner.SignDeferred(document, "sig", fout, new ExternalPrecalculatedSignatureContainer(Signature));
            //}
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PATH + "prepared.pdf");
            using (FileStream os = new FileStream(PATH + "signed.pdf", FileMode.Create))
            {
                PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, os, new StampingProperties());

                // Signs a PDF where space was already reserved. The field must cover the whole document.
                PdfSigner.SignDeferred(signer.GetDocument(), "Signature1", os, new ExternalPrecalculatedSignatureContainer(Signature));
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The next code runs when the sign button is pressed:

```
            private void button_firma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CI ci = Metodos.ciCompleta();
                string datos = Response.Est();
                Sign pdf = new Sign();
                Sign.NOMBRES = ci.Nombres;
                byte[] pdf_hash = pdf.generateHash();

                JObject sign_obj = Metodos.firma(BitConverter.ToString(pdf_hash).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToUpper(), "");
                byte[] signature = pdf.signProcess(Convert.ToString(sign_obj["hashSignature"]), Convert.ToString(sign_obj["certificateFirma"]));

                if (detectarEstadoSinFoto())
                {
                    pdf.signPDF(signature);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Anyway, i tried to see the resulting PDF in Adobe Acrobat and show the following message: "There is at least one invalid signature".

Posible conclusion: I see that my C# program effectively signs the PDF, but I have an error with incomplete signature.

Thanks for reading. Help will be appreciated so much. And sorry if my english level is basic, I'm uruguayan.

Comment: In step 3 (`signPDF`) you create a `PdfSigner signer` only to retrieve its `signer.GetDocument()`. I would propose to instead create and use a `PdfDocument docToSign = new PdfDocument(reader)`. That being said, please share an example PDF signed by your code for analysis.